# How does *http.Response.Body read method work?

Tags: go

Assuming below code, I am reading from an http get request response, How does the Read method work internally ?

Does it gets the data in one go internally and writes based on buf size and on next iteration uses same data with updated cursor or gets the data till buf is full then gets the data again in the next iteration ?

```
var resp *http.Response
buf := make([]byte, 50)
for {
    r, err := resp.Body.Read(buf)

    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Reader interface](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) documentation:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes
> read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read
> returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the
> call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read
> conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

the [Response](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response) documentation goes into a little detail from the `Body` perspective:

> The response body is streamed on demand as the Body field is read. If
> the network connection fails or the server terminates the response,
> Body.Read calls return an error.